# Dumping and restoring postgres roles membership?

Tags: postgresql

I have two 'similar' databases and I'm trying to replicate role membership between them.

Replicating the full database is not an option and they are quite big (about nine hours to restore).

I've tried with `pg_dumpall --globals-only` but it only creates the users and roles, there is nothing about role membership.

On the other hand, pg_dump works with single databases, and I can't find any information about dumping the roles membership.

I probably end writing some script that queries for membership information in one database and then 'grants' this information in the other one.

But I would like to know if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: `--globals-only` **will** include the role membership. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the original ´create role` and `grant` statements and the ones that get dumped with `pg_dumpall` so that we can see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, `pg_dumpall --globals-only` includes role membership.

The problem is that I was migrating and merging two different versions of Postgres. I needed some intermediate clusters to upgrade some extensions, but I forgot restoring roles to them.

After upgrading the extensions, I dumped the data and restored it in the final database without the role information :-(

The whole process takes about 14 hours, so, instead of starting the process again, I wrote a small script to copy the roles:

```
psql --host SOURCE_HOST --tuples-only  --file get_role_grants.sql | psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```

With the contents of the file 'get_role_grants' being:

```
  select concat('grant ', c.rolname, ' to ', a.rolname, ';') as grantcommand
  from pg_roles a
  inner join pg_auth_members b on a.oid=b.member
  inner join pg_roles c on b.roleid=c.oid
  order by a.rolname, c.rolname;
```